# Pandas Dataframe - Bin on multiple columns & get statistics on another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binning

## Problem

I have a target variable `x` and some additional variables `A` and `B`. I want to calculate averages (and other statistics) of `x` when certain conditions for `A` and `B` are met. A real world example would be to calculate the average air temperature (`x`) from a long series of measurements when solar radiation (`A`) and wind speed (`B`) fall into certain pre-defined bin ranges.

## Potential solutions

I have been able to accomplish this with loops (see example below), but I've learned that I should avoid looping over dataframes. From my research on this site I feel like there is probably a much more elegant / vectorized solution using either `pd.cut` or `np.select`, but I frankly couldn't figure out how to do it.

## Example

### Generate sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.random.randn(n),
        "A": np.random.randn(n)+5,
        "B": np.random.randn(n)+10
    }
)
```

`df.head()` output:

```
    x           A           B
0   -0.585313   6.038620    9.909762
1   0.412323    3.991826    8.836848
2   0.211713    5.019520    9.667349
3   0.710699    5.353677    9.757903
4   0.681418    4.452754    10.647738
```

### Calculate bin averages

```
# define bin ranges
bins_A = np.arange(3, 8)
bins_B = np.arange(8, 13)

# prepare output lists
A_mins= []
A_maxs= []
B_mins= []
B_maxs= []
x_means= []
x_stds= []
x_counts= []

# loop over bins
for i_A in range(0, len(bins_A)-1):
    A_min = bins_A[i_A]
    A_max = bins_A[i_A+1]
    for i_B in range(0, len(bins_B)-1):
        B_min = bins_B[i_B]
        B_max = bins_B[i_B+1]
        
        # binning conditions for current step
        conditions = np.logical_and.reduce(
            [
                df["A"] > A_min,
                df["A"] < A_max,
                df["B"] > B_min,
                df["B"] < B_max,
            ]
        )
        
        # calculate statistics for x and store values in lists
        x_values = df.loc[conditions, "x"]
        x_means.append(x_values.mean())
        x_stds.append(x_values.std())
        x_counts.append(x_values.count())

        A_mins.append(A_min)
        A_maxs.append(A_max)
        B_mins.append(B_min)
        B_maxs.append(B_max)
```

### Store the result in a new dataframe

```
binned = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "A_min": A_mins,
        "A_max": A_maxs,
        "B_min": B_mins,
        "B_max": B_maxs,
        "x_mean": x_means,
        "x_std": x_stds,
        "x_count": x_counts 
        }
)
```

`binned.head()` output:

```
    A_min   A_max   B_min   B_max   x_mean      x_std       x_count
0   3       4       8       9       0.971624    0.790972    2
1   3       4       9       10      0.302795    0.380102    3
2   3       4       10      11      0.447398    1.787659    5
3   3       4       11      12      0.462149    1.195844    2
4   4       5       8       9       0.379431    0.983965    4
```

Comment: Would the bins have any specific pattern? Say like constant stepsize? Or even constant stepsize of `1`?

Comment: @Divakar Usually (but not necessarily) constant stepsize, but usually not 1.

Comment: Make sure you award the bounty to the post that you think is worthy. Else, half of the bounty goes wasted. Also, would have liked to see some kind of feedback on the posted answer(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I haven't been able to test them yet due to unforeseen personal things getting in the way, but will try to do it this evening. Sorry for the delay, I appreciate all the hard work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Approach #1 : Pandas + NumPy (some to none)

We will try to keep it to pandas/NumPy so that we could leverage dataframe methods or array methods and ufuncs, while vectorizing it at their level. This makes it easier to extend the functionalities when complex problems are to be solved or statistics are to be generated, as that seems to be case here.

Now, to solve the problem while keeping it close to pandas, would be to generate intermediate IDs or tags that resemble the combined tracking of `A` and `B` on the given bins `bins_A` and `bins_B` respectively. To do so, one way would be to use `searchsorted` on these two data separately -

```
tagsA = np.searchsorted(bins_A,df.A)
tagsB = np.searchsorted(bins_B,df.B)
```

Now, we are interested in the within-the-bounds cases only, hence masking is needed -

```
vm = (tagsB>0) & (tagsB<len(bins_B)) & (tagsA>0) & (tagsA<len(bins_A))
```

Let's apply this mask on the original dataframe -

```
dfm = df.iloc[vm]
```

Add in the tags for the valid ones, which would represent `A_mins` and `B_min` equivalents and hence would show up in the final output -

```
dfm['TA'] = bins_A[(tagsA-1)[vm]]
dfm['TB'] = bins_B[(tagsB-1)[vm]]
```

So, our tagged dataframe is ready, which could then be `describe-d` to get the common stats after grouping on these two tags -

```
df_out = dfm.groupby(['TA','TB'])['x'].describe()
```

Sample run to make things clearer, while comparing against posted solution in question -

```
In [46]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: n = 100
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     {
    ...:         "x": np.random.randn(n),
    ...:         "A": np.random.randn(n)+5,
    ...:         "B": np.random.randn(n)+10
    ...:     }
    ...: )

In [47]: binned
Out[47]: 
    A_min  A_max  B_min  B_max    x_mean     x_std  x_count
0       3      4      8      9  0.400199  0.719007        5
1       3      4      9     10 -0.268252  0.914784        6
2       3      4     10     11  0.458746  1.499419        5
3       3      4     11     12  0.939782  0.055092        2
4       4      5      8      9  0.238318  1.173704        5
5       4      5      9     10 -0.263020  0.815974        8
6       4      5     10     11 -0.449831  0.682148       12
7       4      5     11     12 -0.273111  1.385483        2
8       5      6      8      9 -0.438074       NaN        1
9       5      6      9     10 -0.009721  1.401260       16
10      5      6     10     11  0.467934  1.221720       11
11      5      6     11     12  0.729922  0.789260        3
12      6      7      8      9 -0.977278       NaN        1
13      6      7      9     10  0.211842  0.825401        7
14      6      7     10     11 -0.097307  0.427639        5
15      6      7     11     12  0.915971  0.195841        2

In [48]: df_out
Out[48]: 
       count      mean       std  ...       50%       75%       max
TA TB                             ...                              
3  8     5.0  0.400199  0.719007  ...  0.302472  0.976639  1.178780
   9     6.0 -0.268252  0.914784  ... -0.001510  0.401796  0.653619
   10    5.0  0.458746  1.499419  ...  0.462782  1.867558  1.895889
   11    2.0  0.939782  0.055092  ...  0.939782  0.959260  0.978738
4  8     5.0  0.238318  1.173704  ... -0.212740  0.154947  2.269755
   9     8.0 -0.263020  0.815974  ... -0.365103  0.449313  0.950088
   10   12.0 -0.449831  0.682148  ... -0.436773 -0.009697  0.761038
   11    2.0 -0.273111  1.385483  ... -0.273111  0.216731  0.706573
5  8     1.0 -0.438074       NaN  ... -0.438074 -0.438074 -0.438074
   9    16.0 -0.009721  1.401260  ...  0.345020  1.284173  1.950775
   10   11.0  0.467934  1.221720  ...  0.156349  1.471263  2.240893
   11    3.0  0.729922  0.789260  ...  1.139401  1.184846  1.230291
6  8     1.0 -0.977278       NaN  ... -0.977278 -0.977278 -0.977278
   9     7.0  0.211842  0.825401  ...  0.121675  0.398750  1.764052
   10    5.0 -0.097307  0.427639  ... -0.103219  0.144044  0.401989
   11    2.0  0.915971  0.195841  ...  0.915971  0.985211  1.054452
```

So, as mentioned earlier, we have our `A_min` and `B_min` in `TA` and `TB`, while the relevant statistics are captured in other headers. Note that this would be a multi-index dataframe. If we need to capture the equivalent array data, simply do : `df_out.loc[:,['count','mean','std']].values` for the stats, while `np.vstack(df_out.loc[:,['count','mean','std']].index)` for the bin interval-starts.

Alternatively, to capture the equivalent stat data without `describe`, but using dataframe methods, we can do something like this -

```
dfmg = dfm.groupby(['TA','TB'])['x']
dfmg.size().unstack().values
dfmg.std().unstack().values
dfmg.mean().unstack().values
```

**Alternative #1 : Using `pd.cut`**

We can also use `pd.cut` as was suggested in the question to replace `searchsorted` for a more compact one as the out-of-bounds ones are handled automatically, keeping the basic idea same -

```
df['TA'] = pd.cut(df['A'],bins=bins_A, labels=range(len(bins_A)-1))
df['TB'] = pd.cut(df['B'],bins=bins_B, labels=range(len(bins_B)-1))
df_out = df.groupby(['TA','TB'])['x'].describe()
```

So, this gives us the stats. For `A_min` and `B_min` equivalents, simply use the index levels -

```
A_min = bins_A[df_out.index.get_level_values(0)]
B_min = bins_B[df_out.index.get_level_values(1)]
```

Or use some meshgrid method -

```
mA,mB = np.meshgrid(bins_A[:-1],bins_B[:-1])
A_min,B_min = mA.ravel('F'),mB.ravel('F')
```

#### Approach #2 : With `bincount`

We can leverage `np.bincount` to get all those three stat metric values including standard-deviation, again in a vectorized manner -

```
lA,lB = len(bins_A),len(bins_B)
n = lA+1

x,A,B = df.x.values,df.A.values,df.B.values

tagsA = np.searchsorted(bins_A,A)
tagsB = np.searchsorted(bins_B,B)

t = tagsB*n + tagsA

L = n*lB

countT = np.bincount(t, minlength=L)
countT_x = np.bincount(t,x, minlength=L)
avg_all = countT_x/countT
count = countT.reshape(-1,n)[1:,1:-1].ravel('F')
avg = avg_all.reshape(-1,n)[1:,1:-1].ravel('F')

# Using numpy std definition for ddof case
ddof = 1.0 # default one for pandas std
grp_diffs = (x-avg_all[t])**2
std_all = np.sqrt(np.bincount(t,grp_diffs, minlength=L)/(countT-ddof))
stds = std_all.reshape(-1,n)[1:,1:-1].ravel('F')
```

#### Approach #3 : With `sorting` to leverage `reduceat` methods -

```
x,A,B = df.x.values,df.A.values,df.B.values
vm = (A>bins_A[0]) & (A<bins_A[-1]) & (B>bins_B[0]) & (B<bins_B[-1])

xm = x[vm]

tagsA = np.searchsorted(bins_A,A)
tagsB = np.searchsorted(bins_B,B)

tagsAB = tagsB*(tagsA.max()+1) + tagsA
tagsABm = tagsAB[vm]
sidx = tagsABm.argsort()
tagsAB_s = tagsABm[sidx]
xms = xm[sidx]

cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,tagsAB_s[:-1]!=tagsAB_s[1:],True])
N = (len(bins_A)-1)*(len(bins_B)-1)

count = np.diff(cut_idx)
avg = np.add.reduceat(xms,cut_idx[:-1])/count
stds = np.empty(N)
for ii,(s0,s1) in enumerate(zip(cut_idx[:-1],cut_idx[1:])):
    stds[ii] = np.std(xms[s0:s1], ddof=1)
```

To get in the same or similar format as the pandas dataframe styled output, we need to reshape. Hence, it would be `avg.reshape(-1,len(bins_A)-1).T` and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. I haven't been able to test it as throroughly as I would have liked due to personal issues keeping me off the PC in the past week, but I've player around with alternative #1 for a bit and it seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 5):

If what you are concerned is about **performance** you can use your for loops with minor changes if you use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)

Here you have a function that does the calculations. The key is that the `calculate` uses numba so it is really fast. The rest is only for crating a pandas dataframe:

```py
from numba import njit

def calc_numba(df, bins_A, bins_B):
    """ wrapper for the timeit. It only creates a dataframe """

    @njit
    def calculate(A, B, x, bins_A, bins_B):

        size = (len(bins_A) - 1)*(len(bins_B) - 1)
        out = np.empty((size, 7))

        index = 0
        for i_A, A_min in enumerate(bins_A[:-1]):
            A_max = bins_A[i_A + 1]

            for i_B, B_min in enumerate(bins_B[:-1]):
                B_max = bins_B[i_B + 1]

                mfilter = (A_min < A)*(A < A_max)*(B_min < B)*(B < B_max)
                x_values = x[mfilter]

                out[index, :] = [
                    A_min,
                    A_max,
                    B_min,
                    B_max,
                    x_values.mean(),
                    x_values.std(),
                    len(x_values)
                ]

                index += 1

        return out

    columns = ["A_min", "A_max", "B_min", "B_max", "mean", "std", "count"]
    out = calculate(df["A"].values, df["B"].values, df["x"].values, bins_A, bins_B)
    return pd.DataFrame(out, columns=columns)
```

## Performance test

Using `n = 1_000_000` and the same `bins_A` and `bins_B` we get:

```
%timeit code_question(df, bins_A, bins_B)
15.7 s ± 428 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit calc_numba(df, bins_A, bins_B)
507 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

> It is around **30** faster than the code from the question

It will be really hard to beat the numba performance since `pandas` builtin methods uses similar enhancements.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to numba. This will come in very helpful, not only for this task. I hope you understand that I have accepted the answer by @Divakar because they showed me so many alternatives, but if you can tell me how I can award an additional bounty reward I'd love to do it for your answer.

Comment: I don't think is posible to award multiple bounties on the same question. But the +1 on the answer and knowning that it is useful is enough for me. Of all the `c` compilers for python (like, cython, pypy, numba) I belive that numba is the easiest to use and one with the best performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short solution using only Numpy and pandas. It is certainly not the most efficient way, but I guess the most straighforward and easy to understand way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


n = 20
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.random.randn(n),
        "A": np.random.randn(n)+5,
        "B": np.random.randn(n)+10
    }
)

# define bin ranges
bins_A = np.arange(3, 8)
bins_B = np.arange(8, 13)
```

Till here I use your example.
Then I'm introducing the lower and higher Bin edges using numpy

```
A_mins=bins_A[:-1]
A_maxs=bins_A[1:]
B_mins=bins_B[:-1]
B_maxs=bins_B[1:]
```

Putting this together in a way, that actually you were using those nested loops for, I am limiting myself to numpy, where I can still maintain exactly the structure, that you would get with the nested loops.

```
A_mins_list=np.repeat(A_mins,len(B_mins))
A_maxs_list=np.repeat(A_maxs,len(B_mins))
B_mins_list=np.tile(B_mins,len(A_mins))
B_maxs_list=np.tile(B_maxs,len(A_mins))
```

The new dataframe is initialized with the bin information.

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame(np.array([A_mins_list,A_maxs_list,B_mins_list,B_maxs_list]).T,columns=['Amin','Amax','Bmin','Bmax'])
```

The xvalues column is the most wicked one here, since I have to make it a numpy array to fit in the dataframe. This sub-array is then a numpy array and further has to be treated as one. Keep that in mind, as some pandas functions might not work on that; it has to be a numpy function in some cases.

```
newdf['xvalues']=newdf.apply(lambda row:np.array(df.x[(row.Amin<df.A) & (row.Amax>df.A) & (row.Bmin<df.B) & (row.Bmax>df.B)]),axis=1)
```

Furthermore, you can do whatever you want with lambda functions. As I said, maybe not the most efficient way of doing it, but the code is somewhat clear and as long as you don't need the highest performance as needed for dataframes of millions of entries, this code is easily extended by

```
newdf['xmeans']=newdf.apply(lambda row: row.xvalues.mean(),axis=1)
newdf['stds']=newdf.apply(lambda row: row.xvalues.std(),axis=1)
newdf['xcounts']=newdf.apply(lambda row: row.xvalues.size,axis=1)
```

or whatever you might like.

Using cython, the performance could be improved significantly by avoiding the lambda-way, but I am not used to cython so I rather leave that to experts...

Additionally please note, that there might be some warnings being raised, if you're trying to take a mean of an empty array or std of just one value. If wanted, those could be suppressed using the warning package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In the end I will likely implement one of @Divakar's solutions following some further testing, but I've learned a lot and like the straightforward approach.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree, that Divakar's solutions are the most promising ones in terms of both functionality and performance. My approach might be the easiest one to get it working (for beginners), but as soon as the data amount becomes larger, the I guess more pythonic solutions of Divakar outperformance my way tremendously. Thank you for the nice question, that obviously led to many different approaches for readers on different demands and/or levels of programming skills.